# remove string between underscore and character

Tags: notepad++

I would like to remove everything between the  underscore  _  and  this character |  including the _ character

For example I would like this string:

```
xxxx|   yyy_zzz|    HHHH
```

to be like this :

```
xxxx|   yyy  |      HHHH
```

Comment: Try `_[^|]+` regex. I am not actually sure what result you need, do you need to replace the part after `_` with spaces?

Comment: thank you very much sir its worked for me

Comment: I added an answer with explanations, please consider accepting.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the regex replacement mode and use

```
_[^|]+
```

The pattern matches:

- `_` - an underscore
- `[^|]+` - 1 or more chars other than `|`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qD1oX6/1).